# Call ajax action after submission of comment in wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have searched for this a lot but still didn't found any solution for this . I want to call an ajax action after submission of post comment . How can I do this with WordPress ?

Comment: your theme comment form used ajax for submit comment?

Comment: No . it uses default WordPress form submission .

Comment: Have you done any code yourself? People are not likely to solve this from scratch for you

Answer (score 0):

Without code, I cannot give you the following steps with code myself:

1. Track the event that triggers comment submission and on which DOM element it happens.
2. In the event handler, send an XMLHTTPRequest to server using `jQuery.ajax`.
3. Make sure you create the ajax call in the Wordpress way, and so by sending requests to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and puting logic under `functions.php`. Add the `die()` function.

Comment: Thanx . I will try this out .

Answer (score 0):

I would filter the comment with a WordPress filter. You may not need an AJAX request at all. But I'm not exactly sure why you need AJAX. [To learn more about this filter.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/preprocess_comment)

```
function preprocess_comment_handler( $commentdata ) {
    //some code
    return $commentdata;
}
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment' , 'preprocess_comment_handler' );
```

If you do need AJAX, here's how to make it run in WordPress. You'll need to use [wp_localize_script()](https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/) to get your AJAX to admin-ajax.php.

```
//add wp_localize_script to your functions.php
//make sure to enqueue the js file you are writing to and it's dependencies
function acarter_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_enqueue_script('your-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js');
  wp_localize_script('your-script', 'your_script_vars', array(      
    'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'acarter_enqueue_scripts' );

//do your AJAX call in the file you just enqueued
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {

//Ajax Form Processing
var $form = $( '#button' )
$form.submit( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: '',
        url: your_script_vars.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'function_name_of_the_callback',
            //key : values of stuff you want in the php callback
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if ( true === response.success ) {
                console.log( 'success!!' );
                });
            } else if ( false === response.success && response.data ) {
                window.alert( 'doing it wrong' );
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

You maybe able to send the data to the aforementioned filter, thus using the filter as the callback, but, I've never tried this. At the least you'll know how to setup AJAX in WordPress.